# Pass an integer value from one ViewController to another ViewController and display it in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I just passed the data from one ViewController to another viewController using below process

I want to display the data in UITextField in SecondViewController. Passed value must be a int value.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sendString" object:userID];
```

Change viewDidload method in which you want to get string.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:
```

{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ThingYouWantToDoWithString:) name:@"sendString" object:nil];
}

```
- (void)ThingYouWantToDoWithString:(NSNotification *)notification{

    passedUserID = [notification object];
    NSLog("%@", passedUserID);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger userid;
```

in both the view controllers

then

```
SecondViewController *svc=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

 svc.passedUserID=userId;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

NSLog(@"%@",passedUsrID);
```

and don't forget mention %d for integer.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass data between view controllers using properties

consider two classes A & B, If We need to transfer data from A to B

write the property in B

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *userid;
```

and while pushing to B

```
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
b.userid = INTERGER_YOU_NEED_TO_PASS;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
```

and in B.m

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    aTextField.text = self.userid;
 }
```

If you want to use notification center as you have done above than

chage the line of your code as follws

```
- (void)ThingYouWantToDoWithString:(NSNotification *)notification{

    passedUserID = [notification object];
    NSLog("%@", passedUserID);
    yourTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",passedUserID];

}
```

Comment: i am getting this error:  Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type